# React-Admin: <MenuItemLink> always appears as `active`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

Am using `react-admin`.
I replaced/changed the `<DashboardMenuItem>` to `<MenuItemLink>` (overview).

Unfortunately, this "overview" appears `active` selected all the time.
Any idea how to deactivate it when another menu item is selected?

[image: Dashboard image]

> In the attached image, notice that "Overview" and "Reviews" appear to be selected (`active`)

```js
// Removed this line...
- <DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuClick} sidebarIsOpen={open} />

// And replaced it with this...
+ <MenuItemLink
    to={`/`} // by default `react-admin` renders Dashboard on this route
    primaryText={translate(`resources.overview.name`, {
      smart_count: 2
    })}
    leftIcon={<DashboardIcon />}
    onClick={onMenuClick}
    sidebarIsOpen={open}
    dense={dense}
/>
```

Comment: a working example of codesandbox or stackblitz would be easy to debug

Answer (score 2):

According to [react-router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool), you can do that by add props `exact` to the link component:

```
<MenuItemLink
    to={`/`} // by default `react-admin` renders Dashboard on this route
    primaryText={translate(`resources.overview.name`, {
      smart_count: 2
    })}
    leftIcon={<DashboardIcon />}
    onClick={onMenuClick}
    sidebarIsOpen={open}
    dense={dense}
    exact
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is an interesting challenge.*

And [here's the best way to customize your `Dashboard` and `routes`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html) as advised by `react-admin`.

Here are some quick facts:

- By default, the homepage (dashboard) of an `<Admin>` app is the list of the first child `<Resource>`.
- Nevertheless, you can create a custom component to be rendered as the homepage/Dashboard. (In your case, this is what your are trying to do).

```js
// Method-1: 
// Create a custom dashboard and pass it to <Admin>
import MyCustomDashboard from './component'; // your custom dashboard

const App = () => (<Admin dashboard={MyCustomDashboard}>...</Admin>);

// Method-2: 
// Place your custom dashboard as the first resource
// Note that for this method, your dashboard should return a <List>
import { PostList } from './posts';

const App = () => (
  <Admin>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
  </Admin>
);
```

Using *method-1* or *method-2* makes proper use of the `react-admin` routing/navigation.